# Is that possible to modify a few bytes of a big file without have to rewrite the entire file again?

Tags: php

Is that possible to modify a few bytes of a big file without have to rewrite the entire file again? If it is possible, then how to do it? Or where I can find more information?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) and [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read only those bytes you need. Use [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with an appropriate non-truncating mode, [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) again to the correct offset, and [fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to write as many bytes as you need into the file.

Reference: [PHP Manual: Filesystem Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)